# Formatting Excel to Text Format

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I have formated the excel to treat the cell value as text by appending an apostrophe to the cell value, however i see that the apostrophe appears on the function bar, how can i get rid of the apostrophe or what is the best way of converting the excel cell value to text format?

Comment: Also is there a way i can eliminate the warning message ‘Number is formatted as text’ using vb.net

Comment: Why specifically does it matter whether the apostrophe appears in the function bar? If it makes a difference (other than a visual one which shouldn't impact anything as it doesn't print etc.), then let us know what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell, press Ctrl+1, choose Text format.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells with the leading apostrophes and run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, t As String
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
            t = r.Text
            r.ClearContents
            r.NumberFormat = "@"
            r.Value = t
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```